# UIImageView in appDelegate displayed in simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios-simulator

I've got a weird problem: I want to have a icon in one of my apps that stays above every other Controller/View. My idea was to create a UIImageView in the main XIB-File (the project started pre-iOS-5) above the UITabBarController that handles the Content Views.

I added the ImageView in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    // Add the icon view that shows current working status (working/pause)
    [self.window addSubview:self.statusIcon];
    ...
}
```

Initially the ImageView is hidden, it will only be shown when a button is pressed. Then i will assign the UIImage and unhide it:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.statusIcon setImage:statusIconWorking];
[delegate.statusIcon setHidden:NO];
```

This works in the simulator, but not on a device (tested it on iPod touch 4. generation and iPad 3. generation (retina)).

Could someone please tell my it doesn't work that way? It's not a image problem (it exists on the device, and i tried to load other Image in the ImageView that are displayed correctly in other parts of the app).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same problem once and did not find a solution here. Some hints were helpful though, so I finally nailed it down. It happened only once and I noticed it some days after an xcode version change. However, I never found out what the solution was and if that was really caused somehow by the version migration.

The reason was that the image file was not part of the bundle. Check your boundle settings. Do so for every target that you may have.

My observation was: The image file was included in the bundle on the simulator. It did not only remain there from one version to the next. It was re-installed even when I removed the app from the simulator. I did so either removing it using the simulator's gui as if removing from a real device and I manually removed it from the simulator's file system - just to be sure. In any case the file was re-installed.

On the device it was different. Create an IPA or APP bundle as if you would do for beta testers of for submitting to the store. Have a look into it. (Changing the file name to .zip and unzipping may help to look into the bundle.) I bet that you will not find your image there.

Solution: doublecheck your project settings and ensure that all resources are properly included for all targets respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately thats not the problem i have. The image file exists on the phone, I checked it, and when I try loading another Image in the UIImageView it won't be displayed either. I have no clue why it isn't displayed, but i think it has something to do with the way I want to display the image.